# how to use querySelector to match to specific id after having obtained a nodelist from querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I am using querySelectorAll property initially to obtain nodelists of certain tags,and then from this nodelist i am iterating through each node looking for a certain match to an id property using querySelector,however the result always is null.

```
var x=document.body.querySelectorAll("script");
for(var i=0;i<x.length;++i)
{  

  var y=x[i].querySelector("#myid");   
  console.log(y);
  if(y!== null)
  {
    console.log(i+1);
  }
}
```

i always get an output of null,please help.

Comment: Since ID are uniques you sould just select your element using the ID like this: `var elem = document.querySelector("#myid");` no need for selectorAll nor anything else!

Comment: If you are trying to test whether the current `x[i]` item has a certain ID you can just say `if (x[i].id === "myid")`. If you use `x[i].querySelector("#myid")` then you are looking in the current `x[i]` element's *content* for a descendant element with that ID. But as ibrahim already said, you can select by ID directly.

Comment: id is just an usecase,what if i am trying to match names or some ther property of only a specific tag?i am trying to use a predefined array of css selectors for matching so i dont want to hard-code precise property like x[i].id when i can use querySelector

Comment: I might be assuming too much here, but be aware that querying the script tag will not read the script that each <script> refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select for example `script` tags that have the `name` attribute equal to `myName` use this:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('script[name = "myName"]');
```

You can put as many CSS selectors as ou want to narrow the search.

If you want for example to select `div` elements that are direct children of `li` element, and that have the attribute `name` begin with `"abc"` and that have an `id` and a `class` `someClass` then use this:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('li > div[name ^= "abc"][id].someClass');
```

Here is link to all [**CSS Selectors**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)!

Answer (score 0):

Krishna your querySelectorAll will grab a nodelist for you.  There is no reason for you to add an additional query selector within your loop.

```
var myId = document.querySelector('#myid');
var collection = document.body.querySelectorAll("script");
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {  
    if (collection[i].includes(myId)) {
      console.log(i+1);
    }
  }
```